# Set up multiple static IPs on virtual ethernet interface on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I'm trying to set up 5 static ipv4, 5 static ipv6s and a dhcp ipv4/6 on a single ethernet card (for unimportant reasons). I don't know if I actually need the ip addresses to have separate virtual ethernet interfaces - the purpose of this is to have multiple instances of the same port available for a piece of software I need to run multiple instances of.

I've tried using a netplan config that looks like this

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      addresses:
        - x.y.z.231/24:
            label: "enp3s0:1"
        - fd00:1::231/64:
            label: "enp3s0:1"

        - x.y.z.232/24:
            label: "enp3s0:2"
        - fd00:1::232/64:
            label: "enp3s0:2"

        - x.y.z.233/24:
            label: "enp3s0:3"
        - fd00:1::233/64:
            label: "enp3s0:3"

        - x.y.z.234/24:
            label: "enp3s0:4"
        - fd00:1::234/64:
            label: "enp3s0:4"

        - x.y.z.235/24:
            label: "enp3s0:5"
        - fd00:1::234/64:
            label: "enp3s0:5"
      gateway4: "x.y.z.1"
      gateway6: "::"
```

But its not getting me anywhere - its valid yaml but netplan is throwing an error:

```
Error in network definition: expected scalar
    - "x.y.z.231/24":
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a valid file that actually reproduces the problem, not something *like* your real file. The IPv6 addresses starting with `fd00` are Unique Local Addresses which cannot be routed via the internet. Are your IPv4 addresses `x.y.z.*` public IP addresses that anyone could try to reach or local addresses that are valid in your local network only, like `102.168.*.*` or `10.*.*.*`? In the latter case it should be no problem to show the real addresses. Otherwise use correct addresses from one of the local address ranges.

Comment: @Bodo You too me a little too literally there, barring a substitution for the x.y.z this is the file I used, and that was the result I got. 

the ipv6 addresses are supposed to be ULAs, the ipv4s are also non routing private addresses, but they do route within the internal company network, so I didn't particularly want to share them (the ipv6s do not so I was less concerned). Probably unnecessary but wanted to be cautious