# How to configure multiple permanent static IP addresses (ipv4 and ipv6) spread across a number of virtual ethernet interfaces in 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I am trying to configure the main eth interface as DHCP, and then create 5 virtual ethernet interfaces, each with a static ipv4 and ipv6 address. What is the correct way to do this? I tried using netplan (see [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457075/set-up-multiple-static-ips-on-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-ubuntu-18-04)) but obviously this didn't work

In case its relevant: I'm doing this because I have an application that binds to a port, and I need to run 5 separate instances of it on the same server

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04LTS becomes unsupported in April, 2023, you should consider upgrading to a supported release.

Comment: As you did not get an answer to your previous question you might have to improve the original question. This question here contains even less information.

Comment: @waltinator Its a build machine for a product with specific requirements and as such cannot currently be updated